# C# and .NET: Best way to learn both?

Tags: c#, .net

I have a C++ background and having to develop a larger application written in C# and using the .NET framework. So far I've been reading a lot of tutorials online but looking for books preferably unless there are some really good longer tutorials out there. The project I am working on involves threading, sockets, and GUI design. What are the best books these days? I'm using .NET 3.5 for my application.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As already mentioned, Jon's book is very good. Also very good is Mark's book "Essential C# 4.0".

I was the technical editor of both books.

The books are well named. If what you are looking for is an in-depth guide to the C# language, Jon's book is marginally better. If what you are looking for is thorough coverage of the essential features of the language and frameworks, Mark's book has the edge. But I would recommend either unreservedly.

Comment: Some users have uploaded well known c# programming books `pdf` in Github , Is it legal to download   ?

Comment: @stom: I'm a computer programmer. If you have a legal question, ask a lawyer, judge, police officer, FBI agent, or the like.

Answer (score 4):

Grab [Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet)s book, C# in Depth:
http://www.manning.com/affiliate/idevaffiliate.php?id=876_230
Companion web site:
http://csharpindepth.com/

"The definitive what, how, and why of C# 3" - Eric Lippert, Microsoft (from the foreword)

"Become a C# 3 maestro!" - Fabrice Marguerie, C# MVP and author of LINQ in Action

"The best C# book I've ever read." - Chris Mullins, C# MVP

"Clear and concise." - Robin Shahan, GoldMail.com

"A treat!" - Anil Radhakrishna, ASP.NET MVP

"Reveals C#'s powerful mysteries" - Christopher Haypt, BuildingWebApps.com

"So good, it hurts my head." - J. D. Conley, Hive 7 Inc.

"Enriches the beginner, polishes the expert." - Josh Cronemeyer, ThoughtWorks

Comment: I hope I'm not speaking out of turn here, but I don't think C# in Depth is considered a beginner's book.

Comment: @Jason I suppose you're right, but the OP does has a development background.

Comment: It's one thing to have a development background and to be able to write code and it's another thing to be able to write idiomatically, and understand the depth of features that C# provides.

Answer (score 3):

Follow [Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet?tab=activity)'s answers here on StackOverflow

Answer (score 2):

Without a doubt: [Pro C# 2010 and the .NET 4 Platform](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430225491) (or [Pro C# 2008 and the .NET 3.5 Platform](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1590598849) if you insist on .NET 3.5)

Comment: +1 I love the Apress books for C# and ASP.NET dev.

Answer (score 2):

I'm sure you'll get many responses for useful books and tutorials and such, but for me, one of the biggest helps was installing and using JetBrains ReSharper.  I was already familiar with a lot of development methodologies used by the team I joined.  ReSharper was a *great* way to be *constantly* oriented to C# and .NET-specific standards and potential usages.

[Resharper site](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/)

Comment: +1 Resharper taught me quite a bit too.

Answer (score 2):

[Head First C#](http://headfirstlabs.com/books/hfcsharp/) is pretty good. All the [Head First!](http://headfirstlabs.com/index.php) books are pretty good).

Another good  book is [C# In A Nutshell](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596800956/), from O'Reilly.

Answer (score 0):

It's old, but still one of the the best in-depth books about .Net framework/CLR fundamentals, is Don Box's ***Essential .Net***

Answer (score 0):

For indepth learning - CLR via C# 3rd Edition

Answer (score 0):

[visual c# step by step](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735626707) does a great job of not only familiarizing you with the language and .net, it also does a good job of teaching you to get around in visual studio. It starts out very basic, but by the time you reach the end of the book it has touched on event handling, database access, xml, and even asp.net giving you a solid enough foundation to be able to decide what you want to learn next. Most students in my class had little trouble learning the concepts here. If you already know c++ you might find this a bit basic, but the starter sections could be used to familiarize yourself with the visual studio environment if you aren't already, so they wouldn't be just an extended rehash of things you already know.